# dynamically change the connection string in ssrs reports

Tags: ssrs-2008

hi i need to dynamically change the connection string in ssrs reports. We have a report built in our DEV environment but when it's moved over to our prod environments, (by someone else) we'd like to change the connection to different servers done without the promoter to give the connection string...

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary that in the "Connection String Properties", "connection string" to start a function "fx"

set of two or more "connection string" in function with certain parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this is how i got around to dynamic connection on SSRS report

[Dynamic connections/Expression based connection string SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659211/dynamic-connections-expression-based-connection-string-ssrs)