# Dynamic connections/Expression based connection string SSRS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a requirement to create dynamic connection for SSRS reports where the connection information (Server & DB) will be worked out in c# code, so no interaction with end user selecting(Server or DB).

Catch here is report on its load will connect to specified DB and then populate the several other parameters like dropdowns etc at runtime using current connection.

For same i went down the route of Expression based connection string in SSRS. It all works well till i keep the "Dynamic" connection parameter type "Visible" and during report run pass the connection string from frontend which is not what i want.

How can i run report with dynamic connection from backend and then populate other parameters on report load itself?

Comment: With the expression-based connection string, have you tried setting the connection parameters to `Hidden` and setting them in code?

Comment: Yes i tried that but the report loads with empty controls...if i have it visible and then modify the connection string, losing focus loads the page with all other controls properly populated, but as mentioned i don't want to have this connection string visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured out how to do this...i was doing right things on the report server (setting parameters, visibility etc) but was making mistake on notifying the report service to include the new parameter value during current report execution, so parameter value was being set correctly but wasn't part of current execution cycle.

In order to achieve this i called LoadReport2 method on ReportExecutionService of SSRS
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.loadreport2.aspx

This returns me with ExecutionInfo2 which contains ExecutionId for current report

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.executioninfo2.aspx

Using this ExecutionId and setting value for ONLY the parameter (dynamic connection string parameter in my case) i want to change, make call to SetExecutionParameters2 of SSRS report service

SetExecutionParameters2(executionId, new ServiceValues{Name & Value})

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.setexecutionparameters2.aspx

Now the report runs as expected with dynamic connection parameter as Hidden with no default values and also loads up the dependent parameters on the report using dynamic connection :)

Thanks again to Irb and Ian for inputs

Answer (score 1):

In your report data source add a connection string similar to:

```
="Data Source="+Parameters!DatabaseServerName.Value+";Initial Catalog="&Parameters!DatabaseName.Value
```

Then add the two Parameters to your report. You need to have data source credentials pre-established on the server for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your response Irb...i have implemented single parameter that holds the whole connection string like 
"Data Source=TestServer;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=true;" data source credentials are pre-established as you suggest. This parameter will be hidden from end-user so marking as hidden when i load report the related parameters that should be populated on report load are still coming back as empty. Is there an issue with declaring single parameter rather than two as you suggest?

Comment: I would recommend setting default values for the parameter. If you are using the ssrs api directly then you can pass in in the parameters. If you are using query string access then I do not know if hidden parameters can be set. How are you setting the parameter?